# Adaptación de Woocommerce Yith Quick VIEW

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy teniendo dificultades intentando utilizar una función original del plugin YITH quick view. Quería ver si podríais echarme una mano.

La idea es poder llamar a la función a través de php y asignar los parámetros con variables, esta es la función original:

```
        public function yith_add_quick_view_button( $product_id = 0, $label = '', $type = '', $return = false, $position = '' ) {

        global $product;

        if( ! $product_id ){
            $product instanceof WC_Product && $product_id = yit_get_prop( $product, 'id', true );
        }

        $content = $button = '';
        if( $product_id && apply_filters( 'yith_wcqv_show_quick_view_button', true, $product_id ) ) {
            ! $type && $type = get_option( 'yith-wcqv-button-type' );

            if( $type === 'icon' ) {
                $icon = get_option( 'yith-wcqv-button-icon' );
                $content = '<img src="' . esc_url( $icon ) . '" class="yith-wcqv-icon"/>';
            }
            else {
                ! $label && $label = $this->get_button_label();
                $content = '<span>' . esc_html( $label ) . '</span>';
            }

            ! $position && $position = $this->position;
            if( $position == 'image' ) {
                $button = '<div class="yith-wcqv-button inside-thumb" data-product_id="' . $product_id . '">'. $content . '</div>';
            }
            else {
                $class = ( $type === 'button' ) ? 'button' : 'qvicon';
                $button = '<a href="#" class="yith-wcqv-button ' . $class .'" data-product_id="' . $product_id . '">' . $content . '</a>';
            }

            // let's third part filter button html
            $button = apply_filters( 'yith_wcqv_button_html', $button, $product_id, $content );
        }

        if( $return ) {
            return $button;
        }
        else {
            echo $button;
        }
    }
```

Para poder imprimirla en página con las variables que yo le asigne,¿Tendría que verse así, no?

```
yith_add_quick_view_button($mivariabledeID,$mivariabledeLABEL, $mivariabledeTYPE);
```

Sin embargo, la página directamente deja de imprimir, cuando llega a mi código. El caso es que si hago echo a mis variables, todas reportan contenido, por lo que no le faltan parámetros para ejecutar la función... ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver el error, el log, o sabiendo algo mas, es solo adivinar...

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una solución alternativa. La dejo aquí por si alguien se encontrara en esta situación alguna vez.

El plugin YITH quick view(lightbox utilizado para mostrar y comprar productos sin tener que ir a la página del producto sí), trae consigo un Shortcode el cual te permite insertar dentro de las entradas botones que activaran los respectivos lightbox cuando sean pinchados según los atributos que se les haya asignado.

El Shortcode se vé tal que así:

```
[yith_quick_view product_id=”30″ type=”button” label=”Quick View”]
```

Donde los atributos son:

1. *product_id* -> La id del producto woocommerce[tipo = int]
2. *type* -> Tiene 2 opciones **button** = botón y **icon** = icono(se puede personalizar en los ajustes del plug-in)[tipo = str]
3. *label* -> Es el texto que aparecerá si elegistes botón.[tipo = str]

**Aprovechando este Shortcode**

Aprovechando esto a nuestro favor hacemos un do_shortcode donde queramos nuestro botón/icono y le proporcionamos las variables:

```
 echo do_shortcode('[yith_quick_view product_id="'.intval($id_producto).'" type="button" label="El gran botón"]');
```

Donde ***intval($id_producto)*** será la variable que le inyectamos al atributo con nuestro ID de producto, puedes usar $id_producto, pero no lo recomiendo.

Creo que ***intval*** viene al pelo, pues asegura que el valor ingresado sea INT, creo que me ha dado problemas antes de averiguarlo, pero no recuerdo bien.

En definitiva, esta es mi solución, la comparto por si alguna vez se me olvida... No soy ningún experto pero es la forma que mejor me ha funcionado después de muchos intentos.

Si esto te ayuda en tu proyecto, me alegro de que mi sufrimiento sirva para la comunidad!